# Create a 2D Array with an X amount of one character

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, shuffle

My goal is to make a randomly generated 2D Array in Javascript, that has an X amount of the same one character value while the rest of the values are equal to another character.

In this example, there are 10 rows and 10 columns for the 2D Array. 20 out of the possible 100 values of the Array should be equal to 'Y' (for yes) and the 80 others should be 'N' (for no). I want the 'Y's to be randomly placed all over the Array, and I absolute need exactly 20 of them to be 'Y's and the rest 'N's.

I had a less efficient way before, and I thought to try this approach, where after I define the Array, I make the first X amount of values a 'Y' and then the rest all 'N's. Then I shuffle the array, (using the shuffle from the underscore library) so that the 'Y's are all spread out randomly everywhere.

Is this an efficient way of getting what I need done? Are there any better solutions? I tried making a JSFiddle with my example, but the site appears to be down at the moment.

(I was unable to test my code yet to see if the shuffle worked correctly on my 2D array)

```
var rows = 10;
var cols = 10;
var elements = 20;

//Define Empty Array
var test = new Array(rows);

for (var k = 0; k < rows; k++)
{
    test[k] = Array(cols);
}



var i = 1;

for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++)
{
    for (var y = 0; y < cols; y++)
    {

        if (i <= elements)
        {
            test[x][y] = "Y";
        }
        else
        {
            test[x][y] = "N";
        }

    }
}


//Shuffle all those values so they're no longer in order
var shuffledTest = _.shuffle(test);


//Print in rows
for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++)
{
    console.log(shuffledTest[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution is to first create an array, fill it with a number of "N"s, insert the "Y"s at random indexes, and then finally splitting it into the 2-dimensional array that you want:

```
var tmpArr = [], // Temporary 1-dimensional array to hold all values
    arr = [], // The final 2-dimensional array
    rows = 10,
    cols = 10,
    elements = 20; // Number of "Y"s

// 1. Fill temporary array with "N"s
for (var i = 0; i < rows * cols - elements; i += 1) {
    tmpArr.push("N");
}

// 2. Insert "Y"s at random indexes in the temporary array
for (var i = 0; i < elements; i += 1) {
    var index = Math.round(Math.random() * (tmpArr.length + 1));
    tmpArr.splice(index, 0, "Y");
}

// 3. Split temporary array into 10 seperate arrays
// and insert them into the final array
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i += 1) {
    var row = tmpArr.slice(i * cols, (i + 1) * cols);
    arr.push(row);
}
```

JSBin to illustrate: http://jsbin.com/luyacora/1/edit

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was the easiest to understand and it works perfectly! I like how clean the code is and how simple it really is.

Answer (score 1):

Shuffling the multidimensional array is not the best approach. Seeing as any sort is worse than linear time complexity. The easiest solution would be to create your multidimensional array and then set each index value to the char you want the 'rest' of the values to be. Then for 1 -> the number of other char value choose a random index and set that to the char.

Note: If the randomly picked spot has already been changed you need to choose a new one to make sure you have the right amount at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution, it uses underscores range to create a pair of arrays to use as iterators, though their values don't matter.

Play around with the randomizer function to get an even distribution of 'y's

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/yaletape/1/

```
var rows = _.range(0, 10, 0);
var columns = _.range(0, 10, 0);
function randomizer(mult){
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*mult)+1);
}

var y_count = 0;
var matrix = _.map(rows, function(){

  return _.map(columns, function(v, i){
    var value;
    var y_allowed = randomizer(3);
    var current_y_count = 0;
     if(y_count < 20 && current_y_count < y_allowed){
       var rand = randomizer(5);
       if(rand > 4){
         value = 'y';
         current_y_count++;
         y_count++;
       }
     }
    if(!value){
      value = 'n';
    }
    return value;
  });
});



//The above could be simplified to 
var matrix = _.range(0,10,0).map(function(){
  return _.range(0,10,0).map(function(){
    //put the logic code from above here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe shuflle a 2D array is not the best way. As @Zeb mentioned, here is some code that fill random positions with the 'Y' value. After that, the other positions are filled with 'N'.

http://plnkr.co/edit/avyKfgsgOSdAkRa1WOsk

```
var arr = [];

var cols = 10;
var rows = 10;

var positions = rows*cols; // 100
var YQty      = 10; // only 10 'Y' are needed

// 'Y' values.
for(i = 0; i < YQty; i++)
{
  do
  {
    x       = parseInt(Math.random() * cols);
    y       = parseInt(Math.random() * rows);
    filled  = false;

    if (typeof(arr[x]) == "undefined")
    {
      arr[x] = [];
    }

    if (typeof(arr[x][y]) == "undefined")
    {
      arr[x][y] = 'Y';
      filled = true;
    }
  }
  while (!filled);
}

// 'N' values.
for (x = 0; x < cols; x++)
{

  if (typeof(arr[x]) == "undefined")
  {
    arr[x] = [];
  }

  for (y = 0; y < rows; y++)
  {
    if (arr[x][y] != 'Y')
    {
      arr[x][y] = 'N';
    }
  }
}
```